# display SSRS reports in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I need to display ssrs report from `asp.net` web-api to angular. I am using [ngx-ssrs-reportviewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer). While using this `ssrs-report-viewer` getting 404 error. help me to how to display reports in angular.